# Is there a way to not show the separator in CONCAT_WS when trying to concatinate empty or NULL row's?

Tags: mysql

`SELECT DISTINCT id, CONCAT_WS(' & ', Seek1,Seek2,Seek3) FROM sales`

It group's the Seek1-3 values which seem to work fine, but it also adds & when the Seek2 and/or Seek3 field is NULL of empty.
Is there a way to not show the seperator in CONCAT_WS when trying to concatinate empty or NULL valued rows?

Comment: `CONCAT_WS` should ignore NULLs.

Answer (score 3):

`CONCAT_WS()` does ignore NULLs. Example:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' & ', 'a', NULL, 'b');
```

will return

```
a & b
```

However - It doesn't ignore empty strings:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' & ', 'a', '', 'b');
```

returns

```
a & & b
```

But you can convert empty strings to NULLs with the `NULLIF()` function

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' & ', 'a', NULLIF('', ''), 'b');
```

returns

```
a & b
```

So you can write your query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, CONCAT_WS(' & ', NULLIF(Seek1, ''), NULLIF(Seek2, ''), NULLIF(Seek3, ''))
FROM sales
```

Comment: Since I was working on the use-case example on db-fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7jYi1tE4uC5K2BtaNCxTUe/0